# Headers and Chapters in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007, headers

I have a single word document with 92 different chapters in it. I need to insert a header on every single page which has a chapter number on the far top right of the page. So for a few pages that number remains the same and then when the chapter changes the number on the header needs to increment. I have fiddled with headers in Word 2007 and can't make it work. Then I tried to break the document into sections and now I am stuck with trying to figure out how to link and unlink sections. Is there a quick and easy to achieve this? One of the requirements for this assignment is that I need to deliver a single document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic way you create different headers for each chapter is through sections. Create a different section for each chapter. Go back to the beginning of your document and put in a header (We'll just call it Chapter 1).

Then go to Section 2 and double click in the header area to edit it. In the "Header and Footer Tools Design" contextual tab..."Navigation" group you'll see a button called "Link to Previous" that is already enabled. Click it to disable it and edit the Header to read "Chapter 2" (or whatever you want). That header will flow from that section through the rest of the document. You'd then do the same thing for each successive chapter.

**Shortcut for your situation**

If all you want is the chapter number, there is an easier way. Make sure the document doesn't have any sections yet. Go to the beginning of the document and insert a header with a blank placeholder. Click in the placeholder and on the "Header and Footer Tools" tab go to the "Insert" group and choose "Quick Parts".

Choose "Field" and then in the "Field" Dialog Box choose "Section" on the left and then "1,2,3" on the right and the numeric format "0".

Then create your section breaks for each chapter and it will automatically number the header for that section.